# Integrating Jenkins, Sonar server and Jira

Tags: jenkins, jira, sonarqube

I want a suggestion from you guys. In my current project I have used Jenkins and as **Post-build Actions** I have configured Sonar in Jenkins, which provides me an analysis report of my project, if the build is successfull.
Now I want to integrate JIRA and getting a little confused. JIRA integration plugins are available both for Jenkins and Sonar and the question is: **Should I configure JIRA with Jenkins or with Sonar??**

Any thoughts or views are welcome!!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Everyone for responding. @emelendez Yes, you are right to an extent.
I ran my jenkins job and find out that as I have configured SONAR as post build option, that SONAR part was not getting kicked off if the build failed. So to report a bug I have configured JIRA with JENKINS. And when SONAR Analysis reports any coding issues I also want to log that in JIRA.
Thus the crux is, I have configures JIRA with both JENKINS and SONAR.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't specify what exactly you want to track in Jira I'm not 100% sure, but in most cases it is a good idea to do the connections from Jenkins or Sonar by REST API and just push that data that you need updated, be it default fields or custom ones. Most use cases can be covered by this and from this direction you're unlikely to get problems later when you want to expand your set up or your solution.

Comment: Draugr,  I want to use the bug raising and task creating functionalities of JIRA primarily.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to integrate Jira and Sonar, I think that you want to have Sonar's issues in JIRA dashboard. But, if you want to have release notes updated is Jira after development team has finished their task you need to integrate Jenkins with JIRA.

As you can see, this depend what do you want to do.